# Plotting dates on the x-axis

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I am trying to plot information against dates. I have a list of dates in the format "01/02/1991".

I converted them by doing the following:

```
x = parser.parse(date).strftime('%Y%m%d'))
```

which gives `19910102`

Then I tried to use num2date

```
import matplotlib.dates as dates
new_x = dates.num2date(x)
```

Plotting:

```
plt.plot_date(new_x, other_data, fmt="bo", tz=None, xdate=True)
```

But I get an error. It says "ValueError: year is out of range". Any solutions?

Comment: help(num2date): "x is a float value which gives one plus the number of days since 0001-01-01", so x=19910102 does not correspond to 02 Jan 1991

Comment: What is parser in this question?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As @KyssTao has been saying, `help(dates.num2date)` says that the `x` has to be a float giving the number of days since 0001-01-01 plus one. Hence, `19910102` is not 2/Jan/1991, because if you counted 19910101 days from 0001-01-01 you'd get something in the year 54513 or similar (divide by 365.25, number of days in a year).

Use `datestr2num` instead (see `help(dates.datestr2num)`):

```
new_x = dates.datestr2num(date) # where date is '01/02/1991'
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could add the `import` statement as well, to help python novices like me.

Comment: @kkuilla If this is still relevant, I'm guessing he has it as `import matplotlib.dates as dates`

Comment: @IraI.I. You meant `from matplotlib import dates`?

Answer (score 189):

You can do this more simply using `plot()` instead of `plot_date()`.

First, convert your strings to instances of Python `datetime.date`:

```
import datetime as dt

dates = ['01/02/1991','01/03/1991','01/04/1991']
x = [dt.datetime.strptime(d,'%m/%d/%Y').date() for d in dates]
y = range(len(x)) # many thanks to Kyss Tao for setting me straight here
```

Then plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @bernie Thanks, it really helped me. However, in my problem I have too many days, so the whole plot gets clogged up. How to show every fifth date, or every tenth date on the x-axis with your method?

Comment: @erik I know this is a bit late, but I removed the two set_major lines and that cleared it up for me. Lost some functionality, but still an improvement.

Comment: Unfortunately, it shows me not 3 dates, but 6 other dates (in that interval though). Using matplotlib-1.5.1

Comment: Your example (from 2012) does not work for me (in 2023): I get
`TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.date'` for `plt.plot(x, y)`. Using “Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44)
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux”, matplotlib 3.7.1.

Comment: You can use the interval argument to set the number of days, or use other locators like MonthLocator [from the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DayLocator). E.g.: `plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=7))`

Answer (score 83):

I have too low reputation to add comment to @bernie response, with response to @user1506145. I have run in to same issue.

[image: 1]

The answer to it is an interval parameter which fixes things up

[image: 2]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

np.random.seed(1)

N = 100
y = np.random.rand(N)

now = dt.datetime.now()
then = now + dt.timedelta(days=100)
days = mdates.drange(now,then,dt.timedelta(days=1))

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=5))
plt.plot(days,y)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please note that if you are taking the first date of a series or index and the last date, then since this is a range the last date will be cutoff, and you will run into errors with your code. Assuming you have a `Date` column on your index, then you can do: `days = mdates.drange(d1.index.min(),d1.index.max() + dt.timedelta(days=1),dt.timedelta(days=1))`. Essentially, I added 1 day to the the date of the upperbound value of the range.

Comment: What changes should I do in Jacek Szałęga's code in order, not to assign random dates on x-axis, but put on x-axis dates gathered/sampled from excel file?

Comment: Better to use `mdates.AutoDateLocator()` instead of `mdates.DayLocator(interval=5)` here to automatically calculate how many date labels should be shown on the x-axis. This may answer @just_learning 's question above.

Answer (score 3):

Adapting @Jacek Szałęga's answer for the use of a figure `fig` and corresponding axes object `ax`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

np.random.seed(1)

N = 100
y = np.random.rand(N)

now = dt.datetime.now()
then = now + dt.timedelta(days=100)
days = mdates.drange(now,then,dt.timedelta(days=1))


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    
ax.plot(days,y)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=5))
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=45)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
date = raw_date[:20]
# plot lines
plt.plot(date,target[:20] , label = "Real")
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('Ylabel', fontsize=10)
plt.legend()
plt.title('Date to show')
plt.xticks(date_to_show_as_list,rotation=90)
plt.figure().set_figwidth(30)
plt.show()
```