# replace numbers on X axis with dates when using line plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting a straight line plot with an array of numbers

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, 0 * x)
```

x is the  array:

```
array([  0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ])
```

The line is fine but I want to display dates on the x axis.. I want to associate
a date with each of the number and use those as my x ticks.

Can anyone suggest something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plotting dates on the x-axis with Python's matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627686/plotting-dates-on-the-x-axis-with-pythons-matplotlib)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control [the ticker format](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#ticker) of *any value* [using a `ticker.FuncFormatter`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_ticker1.html):

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
def todate(x, pos, today=DT.date.today()):
    return today+DT.timedelta(days=x)
fmt = ticker.FuncFormatter(todate)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)
```

and if the dates appear too crowded, you can rotate them:

```
fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)
```

---

For example,

```
import datetime as DT
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

x = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 4))
ax.plot(x, x**2*np.exp(-x))
def todate(x, pos, today=DT.date.today()):
    return today+DT.timedelta(days=x)
fmt = ticker.FuncFormatter(todate)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)
fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)  
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. But this is not what i want... i want my line to be plotted using numbers... i have to pass this line to a mpld3 plugin and it should be JSON serializable. I want to plot the line using my array x but display dates on the x ticks instead.. can you think of something ?

Comment: My apologies.. this code worked.. I wasn't thinking straight. thank you