# Stacked area plot and dates in matplotlib

Tags: python, date, matplotlib, area, stacked

Here is my code:

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
dates =  ['2014-12-15','2015-11-07','2016-01-10']
x = [dt.datetime.strptime(d,'%Y-%m-%d').date() for d in dates]
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
plt.stackplot(x,[1,2,3],[7,8,3])
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

It produces the following plot:

[image: ugly plot]

How do I fix it to have only 3 dates? I followed the following example: [SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627686/plotting-dates-on-the-x-axis-with-pythons-matplotlib)

Answer (score 4):

You just need to set `xticks` with the following command:

```
plt.xticks(x)
```

Just add this line before you display the figure. `DayLocator` displays every single day by default. In your case, you have too many days in between to display. You can just remove line 7 which sets the `Daylocator` and replace it with the above line which sets the ticks to be your dates. This is the result:
[image]