# How to show time (years) on x axis in Python

Tags: python, netcdf

I am having a NetCDF data with one dimension that varies with time for 1000 years (1 year interval from 850 to 1849). I am plotting a time series and I want to show only years in the X-axis (850 to 1849). I have used the following script but it doesn't work.

```
import netCDF4 as netcdf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime

nc = netcdf.Dataset('tas_850-1849.nc')
time = nc.variables['time']
lat = nc.variables['lat'][:]
lon = nc.variables['lon'][:]
var = nc.variables['pdo'][:]

start = datetime.date(850,01,01)
dates = [start + datetime.timedelta(n) for n in range(len(var))]

plt.plot(dates, var[:,0,0], color='red', linewidth=2, label='Data1')

plt.show()
```

I get the following image which is not the way I want.

[image]

Time series line plot with time in X-axis.

Comment: One thing that's wrong in your code: `dates` is increasing at daily timesteps. You could use something like `dates = [datetime.date(850+n,1,1) for n in range(len(var))]`.

Comment: Now it is working with the script you have suggested. However, how to deal with the tick marks here. The tick marks shows from 801 to 1801 with 200 intervals and values correctly positioning from 850 to 1850. The plot is correct but I need to have X-axis ticks from 850 to 1850 instead of 801-1801.

Answer (score -1):

As @Robert Davy mentioned in his comment, the dates were not well generated. Once that problem was fixed it works for me using your snippet.

[image]

If you need more information about tick locating and formatting take a look to [this](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html).

**EDITED**

<s>According with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627686/plotting-dates-on-the-x-axis-with-pythons-matplotlib), I'd try:</s>

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

plt.plot(dates, var[:,0,0], color='red', linewidth=2, label='Data1')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. Following the above script, it draws the same plot without any X-axis value.

Comment: I do not have access to that data, but this solution works for me using an artificial time series.

Comment: Please find here the data. [https://www.dropbox.com/s/45zc8sk7vhv6um4/tas_850-1849.nc?dl=0]