# How to plot high resolution datetime given in steps of 10 seconds since epoch for 1 hour using matplotlib?

Tags: date, datetime, matplotlib

I have a question regarding the use of time data and converting to datetime and plotting. I have data every 10 seconds for a full hour in seconds since epoch time. I can do the conversion using datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp). How do I plot the full data but the xtick labels only shows every minute up to the hour.

As an example, pick a year, mon, day, hour, and seconds but each element is 10 seconds apart or time step of 10 seconds.

Edit: Essentially there are 360 data points to plot.

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9627970/4124317 Just use a `MinuteLocator`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. I've got it to plot the minutes but it plots every minute and x axis is too busy. How can I show steps of 10 minutes?

Comment: From the top of my head I'd say `MinuteLocator(10)`, but why don't you check the documentation for it?

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks