# Getting datetime object to print as a real date

Tags: python

I have a text file with rows like this..

```
(datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 4, 16), 0.17799999999999999)
(datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 4, 26), 0.20000000000000001)
(datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 4, 36), 0.17699999999999999)
```

Ultimately I want to read in the data and plot the date against the value, but I'm currently stuck on just getting the data read.

So far I have

```
f=open('data.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    columns = line.rsplit(',',1)                                                                                                                             
    date=columns[0][1:]
    print(date)
```

Sample output:

```
datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 4, 36)
```

But I would like it to print as a date e.g. 20170101 04:36:00 (or similar)
I don't know how to get the datetime object to to get recognized as such, and display as a real date string. If I google it I see loads of info on turning a string to a datetime object but nothing for the other way round.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: So your file actually has raw datetetime objects saved as a string like `(datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 4, 16), 0.17799999999999999)`

Comment: Yes that's right. It gets pulled from a database that way. (Im struggling to format these comments!)

Comment: Why are you pulling from the database and saving it to a txt file? Instead of pulling these directly and processing them?

Comment: We have to keep database interaction to a minimum, so I was just going to pull all the data in one dump then not have to touch the db again.

Comment: How are you pulling from data and pushing to txt, you know you can save the datetime object as a string right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to extract the integers from the datetime part of the string and use these to create a datetime object. You can then manipulate the datetime object as you please to print the desired output:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

regex_match = re.match(r'.*?(\d+), (\d+), (\d+), (\d+), (\d+).*', 'datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 4, 36)').groups()
d = datetime(*[int(i) for i in regex_match])
```

And you can then choose how to print this:

```
>> d = datetime(2017, 1, 1, 4, 16)
>> print(d.isoformat())
.. 2017-01-01T04:16:00
```

Or with more control over printing:

```
>> d.strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")
.. '20170101 04:16:00'
```

So in your code it is:

```
f=open('data.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    columns = line.rsplit(',',1)                                                                                                                             
    date=columns[0][1:]
    regex_match = re.match(r'.*?(\d+), (\d+), (\d+), (\d+), (\d+).*', date).groups()
    d = datetime(*[int(i) for i in regex_match])
    print(d.strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

---

Once you have the datetime object, you can also use matplotlib (you referenced wanting to plot this) to convert a datetime object to a readable string (ref: [Plotting dates on the x-axis with Python's matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627686/plotting-dates-on-the-x-axis-with-pythons-matplotlib)):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
your_datetime_array = [(datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 4, 16), 0.17799999999999999),
(datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 4, 26), 0.20000000000000001),
(datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 4, 36), 0.17699999999999999)]

x = [tup[0] for tup in your_datetime_array]
y = [tup[1] for tup in your_datetime_array]

plt.xticks(rotation=-45) # rotate them if you want
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Note that changing the `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'` string will change the format that is plotted.

Comment: Thanks, I gave that a try. Now I get the error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: And you definitely have the line: `d = datetime.datetime(*[int(i) for i in regex_match])` before `d.strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")`? Note the "d" and not "date" as in your original code. "date" was a string object but "d" is of type datetime.

Comment: I hadn;t the first time but now I have got that all as you suggest. The error is a bit different now. It says AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Comment: Have you got: `import datetime` at the top of your file? Also make sure you are not calling any other variable `datetime`

Comment: I say from datetime import datetime

Comment: Ah great. Then just remove the first `datetime`. So the line becomes: `d = datetime(*[int(i) for i in regex_match])` . I'll update the solution to reflect this

Comment: I just tried it as you suggested and did 'import datetime' only. And it works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

The contents of the text file in your example is valid Python syntax, so if you are sure this format is correct, and the data is under your own control, you could just evaluate the lines. (Note that this is a security risk if the data can be manipulated by others, so this may or may not be a good solution depending on your use case.)

```
import datetime

with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:  # Tip: use context manager to avoid resource leak
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        date = eval(line)[0]  # evaluate line as Python code and get first element
        print(date.strftime('%Y%m%d %H%M'))  # print date/time in preferred format
```

Comment: I was writing the exactly same answer and wondering why the others were not simply ```eval()``` the string. :-)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `eval` or `regex` could be [parse](https://pypi.org/project/parse/) module:

```
import parse
import datetime as dt

f = open('mytext.txt', 'r')
template = "(datetime.datetime({Y}, {m}, {d}, {H}, {M}), {v})"
for line in f:
    x = parse.parse(template, line).named
    Y, m, d, H, M = int(x["Y"]), int(x["m"]), int(x["d"]), int(x["H"]), int(x["M"])
    ts = dt.datetime(Y, m, d, H, M)
    print(ts.strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:00"))
f.close()
```

**Output:**

```
20170101 04:16:00
20170101 04:26:00
20170101 04:36:00
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

```
import datetime
import dateutil.parser 
date = '2014-12-18T19:00:00-07:00'
 datetime_obj=dateutil.parser.parse(date)                                               
 print (date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this applies to strings that are already in datetime object format. Though not apparently real datetime objects.

Answer (score -2):

Lets's make things simpler.
There are two simple and very useful functions in datetime module viz.

**strftime** and **strptime**.

- strftime is "String Format Time". It means it will convert the DateTime Object into a String.
- strptime is "String Parse Time". It means it will convert the date string (in some particular format) into a DateTime Object.

Let me give you an example:

---

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.now()
d
```

datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 27, 17, 55, 9, 967025)
Convert Date Time object to String of format "YYYY-mm-dd"

```
str_format_date = d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
str_format_date
```

'2019-04-27'
Convert String ("YYYY-mm-dd") back to Date Time Object

```
datetime.strptime(str_format_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 27, 0, 0)

> Note: The time has changes because we converted the datetime object to just a date string (lost the time part) and then re-convert that date string back to date time object.