# Cannot plot time series: problem with datetime parsing

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have this DataFrame (small subset of my real DataFrame):

```
household   feed            utc_timestamp               kWh
industrial3 area_offices    2015-10-13 11:00:00+00:00   1.940186
industrial3 area_offices    2015-10-13 12:00:00+00:00   4.847656
industrial3 area_offices    2015-10-13 13:00:00+00:00   7.089600
industrial3 area_offices    2015-10-13 14:00:00+00:00   9.682129
industrial3 area_offices    2015-10-13 15:00:00+00:00   12.142578
```

I want just to plot `kWh` per date time.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
plt.plot(df["utc_timestamp"].values, df["kWh"].values)
plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.1), fancybox=True, ncol=5, labels=['kWh'])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

But dates and times are not parsed correctly:

[image]

When I run `df["utc_timestamp"].values[0]`, I see that timestamps are of the type `numpy.datetime64`:

```
numpy.datetime64('2015-10-13T11:00:00.000000000')
```

The plot looks are follows:

[image]

How can I fix it?

**Update:**

[image]

utc_datetime:

```
array(['2017-05-22T21:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-22T22:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-22T23:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-23T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-23T01:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-23T02:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-23T03:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-23T04:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-23T05:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-23T06:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-23T07:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-23T08:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-23T09:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-23T10:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-23T11:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-23T12:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-23T13:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-23T14:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-23T15:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-23T16:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-23T17:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-23T18:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-23T19:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-23T20:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-23T21:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-23T22:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-23T23:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-24T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-24T01:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-24T02:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-24T03:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-24T04:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-24T05:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-24T06:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-24T07:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-24T08:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-24T09:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-24T10:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-24T11:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-24T12:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-24T13:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-24T14:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-24T15:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-24T16:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-24T17:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-24T18:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-24T19:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-24T20:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-24T21:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-24T22:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-24T23:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-25T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-25T01:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-25T02:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-25T03:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-25T04:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-25T05:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-25T06:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-25T07:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-25T08:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-25T09:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-25T10:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-25T11:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-25T12:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-25T13:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-25T14:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-25T15:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-25T16:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-25T17:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-25T18:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-25T19:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-25T20:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-25T21:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-25T22:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-25T23:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-26T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-26T01:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-26T02:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-26T03:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-26T04:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-26T05:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-26T06:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-26T07:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-26T08:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-26T09:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-26T10:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-26T11:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-26T12:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-26T13:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-26T14:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-26T15:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-26T16:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-26T17:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-26T18:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-26T19:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-26T20:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-26T21:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-26T22:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-26T23:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-27T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-27T01:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-27T02:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-27T03:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-27T04:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-27T05:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-27T06:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-27T07:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-27T08:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-27T09:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-27T10:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-27T11:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-27T12:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-27T13:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-27T14:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-27T15:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-27T16:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-27T17:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-27T18:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-27T19:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-27T20:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-27T21:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-27T22:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-27T23:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-28T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-28T01:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-28T02:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-28T03:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-28T04:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-28T05:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-28T06:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-28T07:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-28T08:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-28T09:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-28T10:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-28T11:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-28T12:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-28T13:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-28T14:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-28T15:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-28T16:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-28T17:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-28T18:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-28T19:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-28T20:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-28T21:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-28T22:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-28T23:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-29T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-29T01:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-29T02:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-29T03:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-29T04:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-29T05:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-29T06:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-29T07:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-29T08:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-29T09:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-29T10:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-29T11:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-29T12:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-29T13:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-29T14:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-29T15:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-29T16:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-29T17:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-29T18:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-29T19:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-29T20:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-29T21:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-29T22:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-29T23:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-30T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-30T01:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-30T02:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-30T03:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-30T04:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-30T05:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-30T06:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-30T07:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-30T08:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-30T09:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-30T10:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-30T11:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-30T12:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-30T13:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-30T14:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-30T15:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-30T16:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-30T17:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-30T18:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-30T19:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-30T20:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-30T21:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-30T22:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-30T23:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-31T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-31T01:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-31T02:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-31T03:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-31T04:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-31T05:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-31T06:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-31T07:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-31T08:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-31T09:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-31T10:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-31T11:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-31T12:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-31T13:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-31T14:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-31T15:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-31T16:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-31T17:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-31T18:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-31T19:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-31T20:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-31T21:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-31T22:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-31T23:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-01T01:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T02:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-01T03:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T04:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-01T05:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T06:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-01T07:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T08:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-01T09:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T10:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-01T11:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T12:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-01T13:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T14:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-01T15:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T16:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-01T17:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T18:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-01T19:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T20:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-01T21:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-01T22:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-01T23:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-02T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-02T01:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-02T02:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-02T03:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-02T04:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-02T05:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-02T06:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-02T07:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-02T08:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-02T09:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-02T10:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-02T11:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-02T12:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-02T13:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-02T14:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-02T15:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-02T16:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-02T17:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-02T18:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-02T19:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-02T20:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-02T21:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-02T22:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-02T23:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-03T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-03T01:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-03T02:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-03T03:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-03T04:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-03T05:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-03T06:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-03T07:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-03T08:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-03T09:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-03T10:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-03T11:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-03T12:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-03T13:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-03T14:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-03T15:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-03T16:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-03T17:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-03T18:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-03T19:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-03T20:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-03T21:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-03T22:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-03T23:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-04T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-04T01:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-04T02:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-04T03:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-04T04:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-04T05:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-04T06:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-04T07:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-04T08:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-04T09:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-04T10:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-04T11:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-04T12:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-04T13:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-04T14:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-04T15:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-04T16:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-04T17:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-04T18:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-04T19:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-04T20:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-06-04T21:00:00.000000000', '2017-06-04T22:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-13T11:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-13T12:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-13T13:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-13T14:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-13T15:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-13T16:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-13T17:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-13T18:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-13T19:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-13T20:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-13T21:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-13T22:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-13T23:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-14T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-14T01:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-14T02:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-14T03:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-14T04:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-14T05:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-14T06:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-14T07:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-14T08:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-14T09:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-14T10:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-14T16:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-14T17:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-14T18:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-14T19:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-14T20:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-14T21:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-14T22:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-14T23:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-15T00:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-15T01:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-15T02:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-15T03:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-15T04:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-15T05:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-15T06:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-15T07:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-15T08:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-15T09:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-15T10:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-15T11:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-15T12:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-15T13:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-15T14:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-15T15:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-15T16:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-15T17:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-15T18:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-15T19:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-15T20:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-15T21:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-15T22:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-15T23:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-16T00:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-16T01:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-16T02:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-16T03:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-16T04:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-16T05:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-16T06:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-16T07:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-16T08:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-16T09:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-16T10:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-16T11:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-16T12:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-16T13:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-16T14:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-16T15:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-16T16:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-16T17:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-16T18:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-16T19:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-16T20:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-16T21:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-16T22:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-16T23:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-17T00:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-17T01:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-17T02:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-17T03:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-17T04:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-17T05:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-17T06:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-17T07:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-17T08:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-17T09:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-17T10:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-17T11:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-17T12:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-17T13:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-17T14:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-17T15:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-17T16:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-17T17:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-17T18:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-17T19:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-17T20:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-17T21:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-17T22:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-17T23:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-18T00:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-18T01:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-18T02:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-18T03:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-18T04:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-18T05:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-18T06:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-18T07:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-18T08:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-18T09:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-18T10:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-18T11:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-18T12:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-18T13:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-18T14:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-18T15:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-18T16:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-18T17:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-18T18:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-18T19:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-18T20:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-18T21:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-18T22:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-18T23:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-19T00:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-19T01:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-19T02:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-19T03:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-19T04:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-19T05:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-19T06:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-19T07:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-19T08:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-19T09:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-19T10:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-19T11:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-19T12:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-19T13:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-19T14:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-19T15:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-19T16:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-19T17:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-19T18:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-19T19:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-19T20:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-19T21:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-19T22:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-19T23:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-20T00:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-20T01:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-20T02:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-20T03:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-20T04:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-20T05:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-20T06:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-20T07:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-20T08:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-20T09:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-20T10:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-20T11:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-20T12:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-20T13:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-20T14:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-20T15:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-20T16:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-20T17:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-20T18:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-20T19:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-20T20:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-20T21:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-20T22:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-20T23:00:00.000000000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

kWh:

```
array([5.90673828e+03, 5.90689844e+03, 5.90706348e+03, 5.90722852e+03,
       5.90738867e+03, 5.90755371e+03, 5.90771875e+03, 5.90787793e+03,
       5.90804346e+03, 5.90974854e+03, 5.91082324e+03, 5.91210352e+03,
       5.91341357e+03, 5.91433838e+03, 5.91545312e+03, 5.91627344e+03,
       5.91711328e+03, 5.91780859e+03, 5.91799805e+03, 5.91815820e+03,
       5.91831836e+03, 5.91848340e+03, 5.91864844e+03, 5.91880859e+03,
       5.91896875e+03, 5.91912793e+03, 5.91928809e+03, 5.91944824e+03,
       5.91960840e+03, 5.91976855e+03, 5.91992871e+03, 5.92008887e+03,
       5.92024805e+03, 5.92310840e+03, 5.92551855e+03, 5.92694336e+03,
       5.92823828e+03, 5.92883838e+03, 5.93013330e+03, 5.93142334e+03,
       5.93278857e+03, 5.93309863e+03, 5.93325879e+03, 5.93342334e+03,
       5.93358350e+03, 5.93375879e+03, 5.93392871e+03, 5.93409863e+03,
       5.93426855e+03, 5.93444336e+03, 5.93461328e+03, 5.93478809e+03,
       5.93495801e+03, 5.93512793e+03, 5.93530371e+03, 5.93547852e+03,
       5.93564844e+03, 5.93581836e+03, 5.93598828e+03, 5.93615820e+03,
       5.93632812e+03, 5.93650342e+03, 5.93667334e+03, 5.93684375e+03,
       5.93701855e+03, 5.93718848e+03, 5.93736816e+03, 5.93754346e+03,
       5.93771875e+03, 5.93789844e+03, 5.93806836e+03, 5.93824316e+03,
       5.93841797e+03, 5.93859375e+03, 5.93876855e+03, 5.93893848e+03,
       5.93911328e+03, 5.93928809e+03, 5.93945801e+03, 5.93962793e+03,
       5.93980371e+03, 5.93997363e+03, 5.94014844e+03, 5.94031836e+03,
       5.94048828e+03, 5.94066797e+03, 5.94083887e+03, 5.94101367e+03,
       5.94119824e+03, 5.94137305e+03, 5.94154883e+03, 5.94172363e+03,
       5.94189844e+03, 5.94207812e+03, 5.94225342e+03, 5.94242871e+03,
       5.94260352e+03, 5.94277832e+03, 5.94294824e+03, 5.94312793e+03,
       5.94329883e+03, 5.94347363e+03, 5.94364844e+03, 5.94381836e+03,
       5.94398828e+03, 5.94415820e+03, 5.94433350e+03, 5.94450342e+03,
       5.94467871e+03, 5.94484863e+03, 5.94501855e+03, 5.94519336e+03,
       5.94536816e+03, 5.94553809e+03, 5.94570801e+03, 5.94588867e+03,
       5.94605859e+03, 5.94623340e+03, 5.94640820e+03, 5.94658350e+03,
       5.94675879e+03, 5.94693848e+03, 5.94710840e+03, 5.94728809e+03,
       5.94745801e+03, 5.94763867e+03, 5.94780859e+03, 5.94798828e+03,
       5.94815820e+03, 5.94832812e+03, 5.94850342e+03, 5.94867871e+03,
       5.94885352e+03, 5.94902832e+03, 5.94919824e+03, 5.94937305e+03,
       5.94954883e+03, 5.94971875e+03, 5.94988867e+03, 5.95005859e+03,
       5.95022852e+03, 5.95040332e+03, 5.95057324e+03, 5.95074316e+03,
       5.95090820e+03, 5.95107812e+03, 5.95125342e+03, 5.95142871e+03,
       5.95159375e+03, 5.95176855e+03, 5.95193359e+03, 5.95209863e+03,
       5.95226855e+03, 5.95296338e+03, 5.95588330e+03, 5.95762305e+03,
       5.95871826e+03, 5.96007861e+03, 5.96124854e+03, 5.96310596e+03,
       5.96397852e+03, 5.96520801e+03, 5.96536816e+03, 5.96552832e+03,
       5.96568848e+03, 5.96585840e+03, 5.96601855e+03, 5.96617871e+03,
       5.96633887e+03, 5.96648828e+03, 5.96664844e+03, 5.96679883e+03,
       5.96695801e+03, 5.96710840e+03, 5.96726855e+03, 5.96741797e+03,
       5.96757812e+03, 5.96820850e+03, 5.97068848e+03, 5.97206348e+03,
       5.97341846e+03, 5.97458350e+03, 5.97582373e+03, 5.97721826e+03,
       5.97855322e+03, 5.97928809e+03, 5.97944824e+03, 5.97961328e+03,
       5.97977344e+03, 5.97993359e+03, 5.98009375e+03, 5.98025879e+03,
       5.98041797e+03, 5.98057812e+03, 5.98073828e+03, 5.98089844e+03,
       5.98105859e+03, 5.98121875e+03, 5.98137793e+03, 5.98153809e+03,
       5.98170312e+03, 5.98430322e+03, 5.98551855e+03, 5.98671826e+03,
       5.98790820e+03, 5.98875342e+03, 5.98980859e+03, 5.99043848e+03,
       5.99061816e+03, 5.99080371e+03, 5.99097852e+03, 5.99115820e+03,
       5.99132812e+03, 5.99151367e+03, 5.99168848e+03, 5.99186328e+03,
       5.99203809e+03, 5.99221338e+03, 5.99238867e+03, 5.99256348e+03,
       5.99273828e+03, 5.99291797e+03, 5.99309375e+03, 5.99326855e+03,
       5.99344336e+03, 5.99416357e+03, 5.99762842e+03, 5.99886816e+03,
       6.00014844e+03, 6.00128320e+03, 6.00219824e+03, 6.00364355e+03,
       6.00512354e+03, 6.00621875e+03, 6.00638330e+03, 6.00654883e+03,
       6.00670801e+03, 6.00687793e+03, 6.00704346e+03, 6.00720801e+03,
       6.00737305e+03, 6.00753809e+03, 6.00769824e+03, 6.00785840e+03,
       6.00801855e+03, 6.00817871e+03, 6.00833887e+03, 6.00849805e+03,
       6.00866797e+03, 6.01083350e+03, 6.01144824e+03, 6.01367822e+03,
       6.01464355e+03, 6.01479883e+03, 6.01495801e+03, 6.01509863e+03,
       6.01525342e+03, 6.01540820e+03, 6.01557812e+03, 6.01573828e+03,
       6.01589844e+03, 6.01605859e+03, 6.01621875e+03, 6.01637793e+03,
       6.01653809e+03, 6.01669336e+03, 6.01684863e+03, 6.01700879e+03,
       6.01716797e+03, 6.01732812e+03, 6.01748828e+03, 6.01764844e+03,
       6.01780859e+03, 6.01796875e+03, 6.01812305e+03, 6.01827832e+03,
       6.01843848e+03, 6.01859863e+03, 6.01875342e+03, 6.01890820e+03,
       6.01906836e+03, 6.01922363e+03, 6.01937793e+03, 6.01953809e+03,
       6.01969824e+03, 6.01985840e+03, 6.02001855e+03, 6.02017871e+03,
       6.02033887e+03, 6.02049805e+03, 6.02065820e+03, 6.02081836e+03,
       6.02098340e+03, 6.02114844e+03, 6.02130859e+03, 6.02146875e+03,
       6.02163330e+03, 6.02179346e+03, 6.02195801e+03, 6.02211816e+03,
       6.02227832e+03, 6.02243359e+03, 6.02259375e+03, 6.02274805e+03,
       6.02290820e+03, 6.02306836e+03, 6.02322852e+03, 6.02338330e+03,
       6.02354346e+03, 6.02370312e+03, 6.02386328e+03, 6.02402344e+03,
       6.02418848e+03, 6.02419824e+03, 1.66406250e+00, 5.26416016e+00,
       8.72705078e+00, 1.16298828e+01, 1.45742188e+01, 1.74165039e+01,
       1.94863281e+01, 2.08276367e+01, 2.21367188e+01, 2.34667969e+01,
       2.47944336e+01, 2.61171875e+01, 2.74741211e+01, 2.88139648e+01,
       3.01650391e+01, 3.15078125e+01, 3.28164062e+01, 3.40874023e+01,
       3.53676758e+01, 3.93798828e+01, 4.29316406e+01, 4.66713867e+01,
       5.00278320e+01, 5.19091797e+01, 7.82446289e+01, 7.95625000e+01,
       8.08925781e+01, 8.22324219e+01, 8.35722656e+01, 8.49023438e+01,
       8.62421875e+01, 8.75917969e+01, 8.89316406e+01, 9.02617188e+01,
       9.15844727e+01, 9.28925781e+01, 9.41621094e+01, 9.54243164e+01,
       9.79145508e+01, 1.01777832e+02, 1.05995117e+02, 1.09109375e+02,
       1.10819336e+02, 1.13514648e+02, 1.17570312e+02, 1.20952637e+02,
       1.23735451e+02, 1.26286850e+02, 1.27832520e+02, 1.29133301e+02,
       1.30478027e+02, 1.31793457e+02, 1.33113770e+02, 1.34433105e+02,
       1.35773926e+02, 1.37123535e+02, 1.38443848e+02, 1.39763184e+02,
       1.41072754e+02, 1.42383301e+02, 1.43662598e+02, 1.44922363e+02,
       1.51083496e+02, 1.56077637e+02, 1.62154938e+02, 1.68268066e+02,
       1.74275391e+02, 1.80260742e+02, 1.85813477e+02, 1.89853516e+02,
       1.92335938e+02, 1.93965332e+02, 1.95283203e+02, 1.96605957e+02,
       1.97943359e+02, 1.99266113e+02, 2.00593262e+02, 2.01923340e+02,
       2.03256348e+02, 2.04613281e+02, 2.05936035e+02, 2.07246094e+02,
       2.08562500e+02, 2.09873047e+02, 2.11154785e+02, 2.12445801e+02,
       2.13743652e+02, 2.15025879e+02, 2.16285645e+02, 2.17552734e+02,
       2.18826172e+02, 2.20096191e+02, 2.21385254e+02, 2.22686035e+02,
       2.23972656e+02, 2.25234467e+02, 2.26542969e+02, 2.27843262e+02,
       2.29173340e+02, 2.30482422e+02, 2.31795410e+02, 2.33132812e+02,
       2.34445801e+02, 2.35756348e+02, 2.37083496e+02, 2.38395020e+02,
       2.39703125e+02, 2.41006348e+02, 2.42312500e+02, 2.43603516e+02,
       2.44882812e+02, 2.46163574e+02, 2.47443359e+02, 2.48734863e+02,
       2.50035645e+02, 2.51343262e+02, 2.52652344e+02, 2.53972656e+02,
       2.55292969e+02, 2.56596191e+02, 2.57892578e+02, 2.59176270e+02,
       2.60465332e+02, 2.61795410e+02, 2.63115723e+02, 2.64445801e+02,
       2.65795410e+02, 2.67157227e+02, 2.68533203e+02, 2.69895020e+02,
       2.71256348e+02, 2.72593262e+02, 2.73892578e+02, 2.75152344e+02,
       2.79173523e+02, 2.83101562e+02, 2.86958496e+02, 2.90730469e+02,
       2.94288574e+02, 2.97567871e+02, 3.00740234e+02, 3.04825195e+02,
       3.07103516e+02, 3.08404785e+02, 3.09686035e+02, 3.10984863e+02,
       3.12323730e+02, 3.13654785e+02, 3.14955566e+02, 3.16283203e+02,
       3.17613281e+02, 3.18965332e+02, 3.20326172e+02, 3.21686035e+02,
       3.23033203e+02, 3.24355957e+02, 3.25632812e+02, 3.27965820e+02,
       3.31247559e+02, 3.33462891e+02, 3.36863770e+02, 3.40575195e+02,
       3.43897949e+02, 3.47589844e+02, 3.51118652e+02, 3.54883301e+02,
       3.58193359e+02, 3.60778320e+02, 3.62958008e+02, 3.64407227e+02,
       3.65918945e+02, 3.67416016e+02, 3.68885254e+02, 3.70365723e+02,
       3.71868164e+02, 3.73377930e+02], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: I'd suggest you check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64) and then (most likely) just run `df['utc_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['utc_timestamp'])`

Comment: @Asmus: Yes, this is what I did already. In my post you see the result after applying `pd.to_datetime`. Otherwise, `utc_timestamp` would be a string.

Comment: Oops, my bad. I had missed the `.values` part. Anyway if you question is only about nicely formatting the x-axis then maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9627970/565489) is relevant?

Answer (score 0):

An interesting option concerning dates placement on the axis
and formatting is to use *AutoDateLocator* and *ConciseDateFormatter*.

Of course, *utc_timestamp* column must be converted to *datetime*
type, e.g. using *pd.to_datetime*.

Try the below code:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

plt.figure(figsize=(10,3))
plt.plot(df.utc_timestamp.values, df.kWh)
plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.1), fancybox=True, ncol=5, labels=['kWh'])
plt.grid(True)
locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
plt.show()
```

For your data sample I got the following picture:

[image]

If your DataFrame contains dates / hours from a wider range,
the placement of *x* labels will be suitably adjusted.

*ConciseDateFormatter* is an elegant tool to "join" date
and time labels.

Read the documentation about *AutoDateLocator*, *ConciseDateFormatter*
and possibly other locators to get acquainted with what you can
do with them.

Comment: On my full DataFrame, this code creates exactly the same plot as I showed in my post. Of course, I use `pd.to_datetime` and `df.utc_timestamp.values[0]` shows `numpy.datetime64('2015-10-13T11:00:00.000000000')`. So, it should plot well, but for some reason it plots the mess.

Comment: Please kindly take a look at my Update. I posted a dataset that shows my issue. Thanks.

Comment: My bad, the DataFrame was not sorted by `utc_timestamp` column!!!